# How to join two string type lists to make a list type of object?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, java-stream

Suppose I have a class Transaction:

```java
public class Transaction {

    private String tId;
    private String tStatus;

}
```

Now I create another class Customer:

```
public class Customer {

    private String cId;
    private List<Transaction> transaction;

}
```

Now, if I get a String list of tIds and a separate String list of tStatus, how do I merge these two lists to make Transaction type List in Java?

Comment: you could use a map, that way you know for sure which tId is matched to which tStatus and it'd be a lot simpler

Comment: Why do you get separate lists? This seems like poor design

Comment: What have you tried? This seems like an exercise for students; if it is then it's best to say so. The answer, basically, is to loop over both lists at once with a for(i=0;i<length;i++) loop, rather than the foreach loop. In the body of the loop create a new `Transaction` object and add it to your list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `Transaction` has a constructor from these two strings, and assuming the lists have the same length, you can iterate over both of them and create a list of `Transactions`:

```java
List<String> tIds = /* probably a method argument? */
List<String> tStatuses = /* probably a method argument? */
if (tIds.size() != tStatuses.size()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("list sizes don't match");
}

List<Transaction> result = new ArrayList<>(tIds.size());
for (int i = 0; i < tIds.size(); ++i) {
    result.add(new Transaction(tIds.get(i), tStatuses.get(i)));
}
```

Or, arguably more elegantly, use a stream instead of a loop:

```java
List<Transaction> result =
   IntStream.range(0, tIds.size())
            .mapToObj(i -> new Transaction(tIds.get(i), tStatuses.get(i)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```